# What's that sci-fi book where phones are dropped from orbit?

Tags: story-identification, warfare, novel

What's that sci-fi book where phones are dropped from orbit?  People are able to ask for things which are then manufactured and delivered to them.  I think the scheme is used to bring down an oppressive government.  I read this book a few years ago, and now I'm looking for more by this author.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*Singularity Sky* by Charles Stross. There's a direct sequel, *Iron Sunrise*, and Stross has been a fairly prolific author over the past decade, with a number of ongoing series. His best known work is probably *Accelerando*.

Comment: *Saturn's Children* is pretty definitely not the same universe as *Singularity Sky* -- no FTL travel, and humanity is extinct.

Comment: I think a case could be made for the Eschaton books existing in the same universe as *Accelerando*. It would be harder to make the same case for *Saturn's Children*, though Stross does leave open the possibility that humans will make a comeback in *Saturn*.

Comment: Saturn's Children has a sequel, Neptune's Brood, released in 2013.